# ¿Convertir Integer a String, con ceros delante?

Tags: java, string, integer

Estoy manipulando fechas, y necesito convertir ints a String sin que pierda el número de delante.

Es decir, 01, 02, 03, 04

He probado `String.valueOf()` y `Integer.ToString()`, pero me elimina el cero de la izquierda

gracias de antemano

Comment: Paco, deseas eliminar los ceros de la derecha unicamente?, especifica en tu pregunta. Cuales serían los valores originales que deseas manipular?

Answer (score 4):

Si la idea es que el número siempre ocupe dos posiciones, complentado sobre la izquierda con ceros, deberías usar algo así:

```
String.format("%02d", miVariableNumerica);
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: Gracias, voy a probar

Comment: ¿Te funcionó el ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es agregar un `padding` de ceros a la izquierda (`leading zeros`), aplica un formato:

```
 int valorNumerico = 2;
 String cadena = String.format("%02d" , valorNumerico);
```

de acuerdo a lo anterior `cadena` tendra un valor de :

```
02
```

---

Si lo que deseas es eliminar todos los ceros, una opción sería usando esta `REGEX`

```
s.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "")
```

ejemplo:

```
String  cadena = "000012";
cadena = cadena.replaceFirst("^0+(?!$)", "");
```

el resultado de `cadena` seria:

```
12
```

---

Comment: Creo que lo que quiere hacer es justamente lo contrario, que no le elimine los ceros de la izquierda.